# Question on two possible infinite series of $\frac{4}{3-2x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I first worked with this expression as follows:
$$\frac{4}{3-2x^2} = \frac{1}{\frac{3-2x^2}{4}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{2x^2+1}{4}}$$

Knowing that this is in the form of $\frac{1}{1-u}$ (which can be expressed as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {u}^n$), I converted my example to:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\left(\frac{2x^2+1}{4}\right)}^n; \frac{2x^2+1}{4} < 1 \rightarrow \frac{-\sqrt6}{2} < x < \frac{\sqrt6}{2}$$

Then, I worked with it as so:
$$\frac{4}{3-2x^2} = \frac {4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}x^2} $$

From which I converted into the infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac 43\left(\frac{2x^2}{3}\right)}^n; \frac {2x^2}{3} < 1 \rightarrow \frac{-\sqrt6}{2} < x < \frac{\sqrt6}{2}$$

> How can I modify one series so that can convert it to the other? I am finding it difficult to understand why these two series are the same.

Comment: My guess is that the binomial theorem is your only hope.

Comment: What are the centers of convergence in these series?

Comment: @Nosrati

After googling what the centers of convergence are, I couldn't find any way to convert these series into the form $ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$

Comment: You simply see that both series equal $\frac4{3-2x^2}$? It's unclear what you're expecting from us here.

Comment: @Nosrati One of these is not a power series. What are you trying to get at?